# Trying to render Chart.js in react, Variable can't be used in <div> id tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to render Chart.js graph on React but I can't use the variable for 
That's why I can't render the chart even though the I have installed the Chart.js for React.

Error - myChart1 is assigned a value not used.

```
const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext("2d"); 
    const myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: AGE,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'VCD [E6 cell/ml]',
                data: BLEED_PID_CTRL_SP,
                backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',       
                borderColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    title: {
                        color: 'red',
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Age'
                    }
                },
                y: {                            
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                downsample: {
                enabled: true,
                threshold: 100 // max number of points to display per dataset
                }
            }
        },

    })
```

This is the Render Part, where I am not getting the "myChart1" as the value in the ID.

```
return (
  <div className="App">
      <div class ="col-sm-8 offset-2 my-5">
        <div class='card'>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>VCD</h5>
                <hr></hr>
                <canvas id={"myChart1"} ></canvas>
                <hr></hr>
                <canvas id="myChart2" ></canvas>
            </div>       
        </div>
      </div> 
)
```

Comment: `const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1')` - this isn't how you do things with React...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate component for Chart and then just call that component in your code which is much easier.

Something like this:

```
   class UniversalChart extends Component {
state = {
    
}

chartRef = React.createRef();



componentDidMount() {

    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

   

    new Chart(myChartRef, {
        type: {},
        data: { labels: {}, datasets: {} },
        options: {}
    })

}

render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.chartRef} height={this.props.height} />
}

}

export default UniversalChart;
```

And then call that component in a different component by just passing a few relevant props. That's how I did it.

Here is how to add data as props.

```
  const chartData = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Market Rx",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(26,179,148,0.5)',
                borderColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.7)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }, {
                label: "Product Rx",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)',
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                data: [50, 60, 70, 15, 60, 20, 70]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        // maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Sales trend'
        },
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stepSize: 20
                }
            }]
        }
    }
 }
```

Inside return

```
   return(
   <div>
                            <UniversalChart
                                type={chartData.type}
                                data={chartData.data}
                                options={chartData.options}
                            />
                        </div>
     )
```

And the UniversalChart comp will be modified to this:

```
   class UniversalChart extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
chartRef = React.createRef();

componentDidMount () {
    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
    new Chart(myChartRef, {
        type: this.props.type,
        data: this.props.data,
        options: this.props.options,
        plugins: this.props.plugins
    })
}

render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.chartRef} />
}

}
```

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer is correct, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Sure, will do. Will it be same for multiple graphs?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same component for multiple graphs as well, just pass in the 'type' prop into it along with the relevant data and option props. The props will be similar to JSON.

Comment: Can you please give me a small example? I am new at this

Comment: Also added a new type of Universal chart comp